# Resolving unmet lib dependencies in Raspbian Jessie

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie

I am trying to create a sensor for a project at my job (project from this website 
http://measurethefuture.net/build/) using a Raspberry Pi 3B. However, I have been stuck for some time with dependency errors that seem to be preventing me from continuing the configuration of the program/software that runs on the RPi sensor. When I do sudo apt-get update, it seems to run fine. When I run sudo apt-get upgrade, I get the following messages about dependencies:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 opencv : Depends: libavcodec57 (>= 7:3.2.10) but it is not installable or
                   libavcodec-extra57 (>= 7:3.2.10) but it is not installable
          Depends: libavformat57 (>= 7:3.2.10) but it is not installable
          Depends: libpng16-16 (>= 1.6.2-1) but it is not installable
          Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 6) but 4.9.2-10+deb8u2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Running sudo apt-get -f install does not seem to work to update the dependency errors. It removes (or seems to remove) the previous installation of the software OpenCV:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  pix-icons pix-plym-splash pixel-wallpaper
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  opencv
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 60.8 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 117980 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing opencv (3.4.1) ...
dpkg: warning: while removing opencv, directory '/usr/local/lib/python2.7' not empty so not removed
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18+deb8u10) ...
```

Then when I try to reinstall OpenCV (using the same command from the installation file but putting it into the terminal manually), I also get similar problems:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo dpkg -i opencv_3.4.1_armhf.deb
(Reading database ... 117980 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack opencv_3.4.1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking opencv (3.4.1) over (3.4.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of opencv:
 opencv depends on libavcodec57 (>= 7:3.2.10) | libavcodec-extra57 (>= 7:3.2.10); however:
  Package libavcodec57 is not installed.
  Package libavcodec-extra57 is not installed.
 opencv depends on libavformat57 (>= 7:3.2.10); however:
  Package libavformat57 is not installed.
 opencv depends on libpng16-16 (>= 1.6.2-1); however:
  Package libpng16-16 is not installed.
 opencv depends on libstdc++6 (>= 6); however:
  Version of libstdc++6:armhf on system is 4.9.2-10+deb8u2.

dpkg: error processing package opencv (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18+deb8u10) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 opencv
```

I feel I have been going in circles. I have resorted to manual installation because this tutorial's installation file doesn't seem to work. How can I resolve these dependency issues? I am hoping once they are resolved, I can try with the rest of the software installations and get this thing working. I have tried Googling and looking for the packages for Jessie (this tutorial uses this version of Raspian) and manually installing each one, but that hasn't worked. Any other ideas? Should I try with Buster? I am very new to working with RPi and Linux OSs in general.

Comment: Jessie is obsolete (technically not, but there are no updates and never will be) and noone is supporting packages for Jessie  so don't waste your time (and ours) asking about it. If you are happy using Jessie by all means do so, but don't expect anything since 2017 to work.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This is my very first project with Raspberry Pi, so I have no prior experience to measure by. However, this is good to know as I can explain this to my colleagues (and stop wasting time on it). Thanks again!